# I can't update a specific slide and I get a "Powerpoint content error"

Tags: openxml-sdk

I have a excel sheet with one chart which is the source. My target is a powerpoint presentation with 3 slides. I need to update slide #3 with the Chart in the excel file.

After executing the application and when I try to open the pptx file I get a "Powerpoint found a problem with content". After I repair I notice that I always get a blank slide in Slide #2 which shows I am not updating the correct slide.

What should I do to go to the slide based on slide no. (I don't have chart titles in the powerpoint slide and the excel chart) and why am I getting a invalid content error.

I Would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using OpenXmlPkg = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace ExportChart
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string SourceFile = "Projected Sales.xlsx";
        string TargetFile = "Projected Sales.pptx";
        string targetppt = "Generatedppt.pptx";

        ChartPart chartPart;
        ChartPart newChartPart;
        SlidePart slidepartbkMark = null;
        string chartPartIdBookMark = null;

        File.Copy(TargetFile, targetppt, true);

        //Powerpoint document 
        using (OpenXmlPkg.PresentationDocument pptPackage = OpenXmlPkg.PresentationDocument.Open(targetppt, true))
        {

            OpenXmlPkg.PresentationPart presentationPart = pptPackage.PresentationPart;

            var secondSlidePart = pptPackage.PresentationPart.SlideParts.Skip(1).Take(1);
            foreach (var slidepart in pptPackage.PresentationPart.SlideParts)
            {

            slidepartbkMark = slidepart;

                if (slidepart.GetPartsCountOfType<ChartPart>() != 0)
                {
                    chartPart = slidepart.ChartParts.First();
                    chartPartIdBookMark = slidepart.GetIdOfPart(chartPart);
                    slidepart.DeletePart(chartPart);
                    slidepart.Slide.Save();
                }

                //return;
            }

            newChartPart = slidepartbkMark.AddNewPart<ChartPart>(chartPartIdBookMark);

            ChartPart saveXlsChart = null;
            using (SpreadsheetDocument xlsDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(SourceFile.ToString(), true))
            {
                WorkbookPart xlsbookpart = xlsDocument.WorkbookPart;

                foreach (var worksheetPart in xlsDocument.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts)
                {
                    if (worksheetPart.DrawingsPart != null)
                        if (worksheetPart.DrawingsPart.ChartParts.Any())
                        {
                            saveXlsChart = worksheetPart.DrawingsPart.ChartParts.First();
                        }
                }


                newChartPart.FeedData(saveXlsChart.GetStream());
                slidepartbkMark.Slide.Save();
                xlsDocument.Close();
                pptPackage.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is anybody who is looking how to identify a slide with a slide number you need to do the following

```
//Get the relationship id 
SlideIdList s = documentPart.Presentation.SlideIdList;
SlideId nslideid = (SlideId)s.ElementAt(slideno-1); //slide no is the number of the slide
string slidRelId = nslideid.RelationshipId;
```

Next iterate through each slide using a loop. Within the foreach loop add the following code to see if a slide has a particular relationship id

```
//  get the relationshipid of the current slide 
    string thisSlideno = documentPart.GetIdOfPart(slidePart);
    if (thisSlideno == slidRelId)
    {
        //do your actions
    }
```

I hope this is helpful